# HTML SVG <image> is blurry/cropped corners

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following HTML code containing an  element for presenting a SVG:

```
<div class="item">
    <div id="item_sla">
    <image title="imagetitle" src="SVGImage.svg"/>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.item {
    height: 95.5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#item_sla {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    object-fit: center;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 23px;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

However, the SVG image is unfortunately blurry i.e. has cropped corners. I've read so far the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171475/svg-image-blurry-at-specific-zoom-levels-in-chrome), but unfortunately I cannot get it right.

Any hint onto why this happens?

Comment: is the height of .item the same as the image?

Comment: No it isn't - the height of the item is fixed at 95.5px as you can see in the CSS code snipped above

Comment: That shouldn't matter for SVG anyway...

Comment: This questuion can't be definitively answered without seeing the contents of the SVG. Or at least knowing what its `width`, `height` and `viewBox` are set to.  Please post the SVG file into your question.  Also fix the errors in your sample: close the `item_sla` div and rename the incorrect `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'image' to 'img' and close the second div
As follows:

```
<div class="item">
    <div id="item_sla">
    <img title="imagetitle" src="Nutshell.svg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```